# subform footer disabled when allowAdditions =No

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a main form of `orders` and a subform of `Items`. The datasheet subform has a hidden footer which is equal to `=sum([price]*[quantity])`. On my mainform I have a textbox which is now equal to `=forms!orders.items.form.sum` this worked fine whilst `allowAdditions` on my subform was set to `YES` and shows the value of the hidden box.

I want to set the `allowAdditions` of my subform to be `NO` so Items can only be added via a new popup form. However, this now causes an `#error` on my mainform total textbox.

- Can anyone help me with an alternative method or workaround?
- Any ideas on why the footer appears to be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

you can make Lock only to the field you like not edit. you can make by Macro ReadOnly. post your sample so we can see what you mean and easier find the solution.

Comment: I will when I get chance. I specifically want to remove the star field at the bottom of the data sheet sub form, which can be done by turning allow additions to NO. But the stops my totals working

Comment: Kindly provide sample from your db so to be clear. because your request need create table and relationship and forms, and we dont know exactly what the output need only after see sample.